# Dijkstra shortest path with minimum steps

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, dijkstra

i need to implement a program that given a directed graph with positive costs at the arcs prints the minimum cost to go from x to y and the minimum numer of steps of all the paths that go from x to y with such minimum cost.
I have written a program that does that, but sometimes it takes a path that doesn't have the minimum number of steps.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> Warc;
typedef vector<vector<Warc>> Wgraph;

int dijkstra(const Wgraph& g, int x, int y, vector<int>& p) {
  int n = g.size();
  vector<int> d(n, INT_MAX); //costs
  p = vector<int>(n, -1); //parent of each vertice
  d[x] =0;
  vector<bool> S(n, false);
  priority_queue<Warc, vector<Warc>, greater<Warc>> Q;
  Q.push(Warc(0, x));
  while(not Q.empty()) {
    int u = Q.top().second;
    Q.pop();
    if(u == y) return d[u];
    if(not S[u]) {
      S[u] = true;
      for(Warc a : g[u]) {
        int v = a.second;
        int c = a.first;
        if(d[v] > d[u] + c) {
         d[v] = d[u] + c;
         p[v] = u;
         Q.push(Warc(d[v], v));
       }
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

int main() {
  int n; //# of vertices
  while(cin >> n) {
    int m; //# of arcs
    cin >> m;
    Wgraph g(n);
    for(int i = 0; i<m; ++i) {
      int u, v;
      int c;
      cin >> u >> v >> c; // arc: u->v with cost C
      g[u].push_back(make_pair(c, v));
    }
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y; //origin and end
    vector<int> p; //p[i]= parent of vertice i
    int path = dijkstra(g, x, y, p);
    if(path == -1) cout << "no path from " << x << " to " << y << endl;
    else {
        int s = 0;
        int i = y;
        while(i != x) {
            ++s;
            i = p[i];
        }
        cout << "cost " << path-s << ", " << s << " step(s)" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code?  Have you tried to break it down into smaller units and write unit tests for them?

Comment: Note that the complexit of your implementation will be `O(m log m)` while it it should be `O(n log n)` (where `n` is the number of nodes and `m` is the number of edges): your priority queue stores edges while it needs to store nodes. It also needs to move nodes within the priority queue, an operation which `std::priority_queue<T>` doesn't support.

Comment: Your algorithm uses the first shortest path it finds only. If the last step in the minimum step part is tiny while the last step in a more steps path larger, the more step path will be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only consider the distance in the priority queue. As a result, a random last edge will be used to complete the path but only one of them will be considered. You could create a more advanced distance which takes the length of the path into account in addition to the distance: the primary weight would be the distance but for equal distance you'd consider the edge coming from a shorter path to be shorter.

Note that your algorithm has the wrong complexity: it has complexity `O(m log m)` instead of `O(n log n)` (`n` being the number of nodes and `m` being the number of edges) because you store edges in your priority queue instead of nodes. Dijstra's algorithm is only efficient when storing nodes and adjusting their location in the priority queue as needed - an operation not supported by `std::priority_queue<T>`.